# Dell ServerAdmin SMTP settings with username/password

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

Dell's OpenManager server admin tool can send email alerts, but the config for the SMTP server has no field to enter username/password.

Can it only make use of non-authenticated SMTP servers, or is there a way to enter username and password as part of the server name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to provide SMTP authentication for Dell OpenManage. I can give you a couple of work arounds though.

The first one, is allow unauthenticated relaying only from your OM server's IP address. This should be done carefully so as not to create an open relay for the world. The process to do this will be different depending on what mail server you're using.

The other option only works if you're sending email to users on a single server. If that's the case, just use that server's name or IP address in the SMTP configuration as the SMTP server name. Mail servers always accept anonymous connections for email directed to a mailbox they hold.

Comment: I think the question is about SNMP [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snmp], not SMTP [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp].

Comment: He said email alerts, so I assumed SMTP. Maybe it's a new combination of SNMP and SMTP called SMNP :-)

Comment: I was wrong on my initial comment. The question is about SMTP authentication, not SNMP authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, the [Dell OMSA User's Guide](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/6.2/en/UG/PDF/OMSAUG.pdf) has a little comment on page 59 that says

> NOTE: For security reasons, your
>   company or organization might not
>   allow e-mails to be sent through the
>   SMTP server to outside accounts.

Which to me implies that you can't do any additional configuration. I think the thing to do is configure your mail relay to accept incoming SMTP from ONLY the IP address of the OMSA Server, as @Jason Berg suggested.